# How to manage file or folder permissions between two user accounts on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

There are two users: the user `jenkins` and the user `nginx` (both are actually the service accounts).

First, the user `jenkins` creates the directory `frontend` in the `/usr/share/nginx/html`
folder. Then it downloads some `html` files saving them in this folder.

Then the user `nginx` tries to open one of the html files and gets the `Permission denied` error.

To fix this issue, I first checked which groups the users belong to with:
`groups jenkins` and it returns: `jenkins : jenkins`

Then I checked what group the user `nginx` is assigned to. And it is `nginx : nginx`

I checked the permissions for the `frontend` folder `jenkins` created as `/usr/share/nginx/html/frontend` and it it is automatically assigned the user `jenkins` and the group `jenkins`. Via changing the permissions for this folder with `chown` command I found that in order for `nginx` user to be able to read these files the folder needs to be set with `nginx:nginx` ownership.

I have also tried to create a new group `workers` and then assign both `jenkins` and `nginx` users to it with

```
sudo groupadd workers 
sudo usermod -aG workers jenkins
sudo usermod -aG workers nginx
```

But unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue. `jenkins` user keeps creating the folders with the same ownership as before `jenkins:jenkins`.

Is there a way to make both users have a full access on a folder created by one of them? What should I do?

## P.S.

Below is some additional info.
The `frontend` folder is created by `jenkins` user in `/usr/share/nginx/html/`. Here are some details:

```
sudo namei -om /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

```
    f: /usr/share/nginx/html/
     dr-xr-xr-x root  root    /
     drwxr-xr-x root  root    usr
     drwxr-xr-x root  root    share
     drwxr-xr-x nginx jenkins nginx
     drwxrwxrwx nginx nginx   html
```

Then, after the `frontend` folder is created I run

```
sudo namei -om /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

to check its ownership and it is:

```
    f: /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend
     dr-xr-xr-x root    root    /
     drwxr-xr-x root    root    usr
     drwxr-xr-x root    root    share
     drwxr-xr-x nginx   jenkins nginx
     drwxrwxrwx nginx   nginx   html
     drwxr-xr-x jenkins jenkins frontend
```

## Answer : Edited later:

Below is a breakdown of the steps needed to make a single folder created by one user accessible by another.

1. Create a new user group and assign both user to it:

```
sudo groupadd newgroup
sudo usermod -aG jenkins
sudo usermod -aG nginx
```

2. Now, after `jenkins` user creates a folder with the default `jenkins:jenkins` ownership, make `jenkins` user change the folder's ownership setting it with `jenkins:newgroup` (note that `jenkins` won't be able to set the folder's group ownership to `newgroup` unless it is a member of `newgroup`):

```
chown -R jenkins:newgroup /path/to/folder/created/by/jenkins/
```

3. Make `jenkin` user to assign `read-write` permissions to the owner `user` (`jenkins`) and owner `group`(`newgroup`) by running:

```
chmod -R 775 /path/to/folder/created/by/jenkins/
```

Comment: You say that you get the permission error when opening a **file**, but you only show us the permissions for the **directory**. How are the file permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try using the "chgrp" command after creating the directory?

chgrp groupname directoryname

After that, do a chmod to allow full access to the group.

chmod 775 directoryname

That will allow both to access.

Comment: `chown -R jenkins:groupname-both-accounts-share /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend`  and then `chmod -R 775 /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend` recursively works well.